# Fibonacci Sequence using For Loop - Don't understand the loop

Tags: python, loops, fibonacci

Very new to python and I am trying to understand how I am getting the correct answer

Write the code that:

1. Calculates and prints the first 50 terms of the fibonacci sequence.
2. Print each term and number as follows:

```
term: 0 / number: 0
term: 1 / number: 1
term: 2 / number: 1
term: 3 / number: 2
term: 4 / number: 3
term: 5 / number: 5
```

I got the right answer but how does the "else" part work?

```
c = a + b
print(f'term: {term} / number: {c}')
a = b
b = c
```

Can someone explain to me exactly how the variable above changes each time it loops? I don't understand how c = 1 + 1 which prints c = 2 but how does it print c = 3 afterwards?

```
a = 1
b = 1
for term in range (50):
    if term <= 1:
        print(f'term: {term} / number: {term}')
    elif term == 2:
        print(f'term: {term} / number: 1')
    else:
        c = a + b
        print(f'term: {term} / number: {c}')
        a = b
        b = c
```

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, the first time we proceed through the else part, we have the following assignment, we apply the following assignments:

```
c = a + b # <-- (1) + (1) = 2
a = b     # <-- (1)
b = c     # <-- (2)
```

So after the first traversal through the else portion, b is the most recent fibonacci number (in this case 2) and a is the one before.  The next time, we do the following.

```
c = a + b # <-- (1) + (2) = 3
a = b     # <-- (2)
b = c     # <-- (3)
```

With this, b has been updated to become the next Fibonacci number, and a is updated to become 2, which *was* the most recent Fibonacci number but is now the one before.

In this fashion, c is always the most recent Fibonacci number, and this value is assigned to b for use in the next loop, and that value of b is eventually assigned to a.

---

Incidentally, you can avoid the logic of the if/elif/else block if you refactor your code into any of the following:

```
a = 1
b = 1
print('term 0 / number: 0')
print('term 1 / number: 1')
print('term 2 / number: 1')

for term in range (3,50):
    c = a + b
    print(f'term: {term} / number: {c}')
    a = b
    b = c
```

Alternatively,

```
a = 0
b = 1
for term in range (50):
    print(f'term: {term} / number: {a}')
    c = a + b
    a = b
    b = c
```

The following also works and removes the variable c:

```
a = 0
b = 1
for term in range (50):
    print(f'term: {term} / number: {a}')
    (a, b) = (b, a+b)
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. This clarifies everything perfectly. Also, the refactored code makes it much more clean.

Answer (score 1):

### Fibonacci Series

In mathematics, the *Fibonacci numbers*, commonly denoted Fn , form a sequence, the Fibonacci sequence, in which *each number* is the **sum of the two preceding ones**. The sequence commonly starts from 0 and 1, although some authors start the sequence from 1 and 1 or sometimes (as did Fibonacci) from 1 and 2. Starting from 0 and 1, the first few values in the sequence are:[1]

**0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144.**

Therefore we can see the to get the next number we are adding the previous two numbers.

Now lets dry run your code

```
a = 1
b = 1
for term in range (50):
    if term <= 1:
        print(f'term: {term} / number: {term}')
    elif term == 2:
        print(f'term: {term} / number: 1')
    else:
        c = a + b
        print(f'term: {term} / number: {c}')
        a = b
        b = c
```

The first two lines:-

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

are specifying the second and third two values in the series.so that we can use them in addition to get the next term.

Then in the 3rd line:-

```
for term in range (50):
```

we are initiating a for loop that would go on 50 times as it is specified in `range(50):`
Note:- This controls the number of terms printed in series. change the number in range to the number of terms you want to print.

---

The next `if` statment:-

if term <= 1:
print(f'term: {term} / number: {term}')
this if statement deals with the condition for the first two terms. where the value of term is 0 and 1. we used the variable term which is in for loop in the print statement to print the term and its value.

---

the `elif` statement:-

elif term == 2:
print(f'term: {term} / number: 1')

we are using this elif statement to print the third term. as we need the third term to be 1 (0 + 1) we are hard-typing it into the print statement using elif statement.

---

## Now the else statement you have asked for:

```
 else:
    c = a + b
    print(f'term: {term} / number: {c}')
    a = b
    b = c
```

This else statement deals with `4th term` and terms after it.

```
c=a+b
```

will **add the previous two terms** as required in *Fibonacci series*.

print(f'term: {term} / number: {c}')

this will print the term and value.

then,

```
a = b
b = c
```

will **update the values** to the *next term*. and the loop restarts with new values.